# How to make white smoke (with Cycles)?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I wanted to create steam and I've implemented the quick smoke shader but it's always grey when I put the color slider on white, and I want to change it to white. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do, works well. I put this on a .vdb object.

[image]